# Have existing carpeted closet. How to install mirrored bifold doors with lower track?

Tags: doors, carpet, closet

want to replace existing top track wooden bifold doors with a mirrored bifold with a lower track. Can this be done without removing the carpet where the track fits?

Comment: measure and cut the trench

Comment: Photos would get a better answer

Comment: @Ruskes OP would also need to retrofit tack strips and/or staple the carpet around the trench.

Answer (score 3):

I have done two ways in the past:

1. cut the strip of carpet away to screw the track down securely
2. use spacers to support the track with longer screws though to the floor, carpet is only crushed, or removed, for the spacers.

Both have worked.

As you are increasing the mass of the doors with mirrors, then the type of door used usually has the upper roller fixings mounted in the door, not just screwed to one face. Some have metal inserts that are drilled, screwed and often glued into the uprights of the door frame - these tend to be the strongest and the track is usually an inverted U with pairs of rollers to distribute the total mass.

Comment: With spacers is the track mostly unsupported?  For a heavy moving door I like #1 a lot more.

Comment: @jay613 the lower track is usually just for guidance and the upper track takes the weight. There are other designs though, but when the doors "hang" then the lower track just stops the doors wobbling...

Answer (score 0):

If the reason for a lower track is the weight of the mirrors, instead get a high quality commercial grade upper track.  You can't buy them in big hardware stores.   They can support hundreds of pounds, glide like butter on a hot pan, and last forever if installed well.

To do this the doors can't be crap, they need to be solid or have a strong frame and there are variants of the top mounting hardware that mount to the rear face of the door so it's not hanging on the screw threads.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the bottom track, and how strong/flimsy it is, I'd go for a nice piece of wood on top of the carpet, twice as wide as the track, and around 6mm or more deep. This will give a firm base for a more flimsy track, but in any case, keep any track from 'floating'. Screw down through the carpet into the floorboards every 300mm or so, then track on top.